# Installing Android SDK: Stopping ADB server failed (code -1)

Tags: android, android-studio

While downloading/installing the Android SDK (`android-sdk_r24.4.1-macosx`), the following error occurred:

```
Preparing to install archives
Downloading Android SDK Platform-tools, revision 23.1
Installing Android SDK Platform-tools, revision 23.1
Stopping ADB server failed (code -1).
Installed Android SDK Platform-tools, revision 23.1
```

It didn't seem to stop the process, so I'm wondering what potentials errors this may bring about and how I should go about recovery.

[image: Android SDK Manager]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ADB stands for Android Debug Bridge and is used to connect a physical device to the computer to debug apps. ADB gets restarted after installing new packages. The warning you get says it couldn't stop the ADB server. According to http://www.sitepoint.com/beginning-android-install-an-android-platform/, it happens because "the ADB server isn’t running at this point".

Comment: I have the same issue, but I don't get that message box "ADB Restart" to hit yes/no. :( How to fix this problem please?