# unable to obtain result for 'adb version'

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

I encountered this problem a few days ago. I tried replacing my SDK with my friend's SDK and it still doesn't work. I tried re-installing my Windows (I am using Windows 8.1 64 bit) and it doesn't work either. I tried deleting and installing platform-tools and I got this error message [image: error message]

Anyone can help?

Comment: Take a look at following threads: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35122000/installing-android-sdk-stopping-adb-server-failed-code-1, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11572577/error-stopping-adb-server-failed-code-1-installing-apis-android-sdk

Comment: @Mr.Rabbit but at their cases the packages were successfully installed. When i re-open the SDK Manager, nothing's changed